# Simple Java text based game loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

so Im creating a simple text based game but having trouble with my loop. So my character has 3 battles with the same enemy but the battle is not over until one character dies. With my current code, it only loops through the first battle but leave battle 2 and 3 blank.
The players HP carries over from battle to battle but the enemies HP is reset at 25 for each subsequent battle. 
And how do I get my loop to stop immediately when a character dies?
What am i doing wrong?

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int characterHP = 0, characterStrength = 0, weaponMin = 0, weaponMax = 0;
    int enemyHP = 0, enemyStrength = 0, enemyWeaponMin = 0, enemyWeaponMax = 0;
    boolean running = true, characterHasntDied = true, enemyHasntDied = true;
    int choice;
    String characterChoice = null;
    String enemyChoice = null;
    int ATK = 0, enemyATK = 0;



    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ATK = rand.nextInt((weaponMax - weaponMin) + 1) + weaponMin;
            enemyATK = rand.nextInt((enemyWeaponMax - enemyWeaponMin) + 1) + enemyWeaponMin;

            int valueOfAttack = (ATK + characterStrength);
            int enemyValueOfAttack = (enemyATK + enemyStrength);



                enemyHP -= valueOfAttack;
                characterHP -= enemyValueOfAttack;

                if (enemyHP < 1) {
                    characterHasntDied = false;
                    System.out.println(characterChoice + " has defeated Goblin " + i);
                    break;

                } else if (characterHP < 1) {
                    characterHasntDied = false;
                    System.out.println(characterChoice + " is defeated in battle!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems some code is not shown, eg. where is `characterHasntDied` defined? Could you include that and the actual output when you run the code.

Comment: Do you reset the values (hp, characterHasntDied, etc)n after the battle? Please provide allways all the important code, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . For example, remove teh parts of your code that are not changing values (like the System.out.printlns) so that your code is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `break` because it will break out of its `loop`

```
   if (enemyHP < 1) {
    /*... */

  } else if (characterHP < 1) {
    /*... */
  }
```

simulate three battles between two players would be something

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
int PowerPlayer1 =200;
int PowerPlayer2 = 200;
boolean winner=false;
int ATKPlaayer1 = 0, ATKPlaayer2 = 0;
String Player1 = "Rogue";
String Player2 = "Goblin";    

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { // i many battles

        while(!winner) /*while there is no winner*/
        {
            /* The Random method can improve it*/
          ATKPlaayer1 = rand.nextInt(200);
          System.out.println(Player1+ "  Attack : " + ATKPlaayer1);
          PowerPlayer2-= ATKPlaayer1;
          System.out.println(Player2 + " Power Diminished by the Attack "+ Player1 + " of "+ PowerPlayer2);
          ATKPlaayer2 = rand.nextInt(200);
          System.out.println(Player2+ "  Attack : " + ATKPlaayer2);
          PowerPlayer1-=ATKPlaayer2;
          System.out.println(Player1 + " Power Diminished by the Attack "+ Player2 + " of "+ PowerPlayer1);
          if(PowerPlayer1<=0)
          {
                System.out.println(Player2  + " has Winner");
                winner=true;
          }
          else if(PowerPlayer2<=0)
          {
                System.out.println(Player1 + " has Winner");
                winner=true;
          }

        }
        /* Reset Variables */
         winner = false; 
         PowerPlayer1 =200;
         PowerPlayer2 =200;
      }
```

Comment: how do I end the loop as soon as a condition is met? for example, in my output:


Goblin attacks with ATK = 6 + 4 = 10
Rogue HP is now 34 - 10 = 24
Rogue attacks with ATK = 3 + 8 = 11
Goblin HP is now 14 - 11 = 3


Goblin attacks with ATK = 6 + 4 = 10
Rogue HP is now 24 - 10 = 14
Rogue attacks with ATK = 3 + 8 = 11
Goblin HP is now 3 - 11 = -8 **end here**
\n
 **instead of allowing extra enemy attack here**
Goblin attacks with ATK = 6 + 4 = 10
Rogue HP is now 14 - 10 = 4
Rogue has defeated Goblin 2

***Rogue vs. Goblin Battle 3***

Comment: with a break exits the forum, so that the first iteration you do that :)